# Log4net with BizTalk 2010

Tags: log4net, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Has anyone used Log4Net within BizTalk 2010 Orchestrations before? Recently I ported my BizTalk solution from BizTalk 2006 R2 to BizTalk 2010. The log4net I'm using is the wrapper written by Scott Colestock. After migrating to BizTalk 2010, the logs are no longer printing but still the orchestrations run without any error.

I tried to add the following to the log4net config as suggested by some (though those usage of log4net are not BizTalk context). Still it is not working. Anyone has any clue or experience in making log4net work in BizTalk 2010?

```
<startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you move to an x64 server and are you running x64 hosts?   There might be something missing for your Log4net to work.  See this [thread](http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/discussions/66255).

If that might be, try run it in a x86 host and see if it makes a difference.

I know it's not an answer, but have you looked at the guide the CAT team came up with around [instrumenting BizTalk](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/05/11/best-practices-for-instrumenting-high-performance-biztalk-solutions.aspx)?  I try to use that when I can.